# Select one type of model from a Drop Down to populate a property on another model in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a model called Player:

```
public class Player
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Wins { get; set; }
    public int Draws { get; set; }
    public int Losses { get; set; }
    public int League { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="GF")]
    public int GoalsFor { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="GA")]
    public int GoalsAgainst { get; set; }

    public int Points
    {
        get { return Wins * 3 + Draws; }
    }
}
```

.. and another model called Result:

```
public class Result
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Player Winner { get; set; }
    public Player Loser { get; set; }
    public bool Draw { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Player A")]
    public Player PlayerA { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Player B")]
    public Player PlayerB { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Player A Goals")]
    public int PlayerAGoals { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Player B Goals")]
    public int PlayerBGoals { get; set; }
}
```

When I want to create a new result the list of Players is added to the ViewBag in the controller and passed to the view:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    IEnumerable<Player> players = db.Players.ToList();
    ViewBag.Players = new SelectList(players, "Name", "Name");

    return View();
}
```

However when I want to add a new result and select the names of two players from a drop down list on the view, these Player properties on the Result object are null. I was hoping that they would contain the Player object.

The way the drop down list is populated is like this:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.PlayerA, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
@Html.DropDownList("Players", "-- Select Player --")
```

Can somebody point me in the right direction on how to get these properties either populated correctly in the drop down list, or how to get the Player objects assigned correctly to the Result.PlayerA and Result.PlayerB properties?

Comment: I don't have your full example.  But you need to create your list items.  You will probably do this by making a loop that adds list items.

Comment: Can you provide a sample on what you want the output to be? Either you return the wrong kind of objects (Player instead of Result) or I'm missing something

Comment: When you say they are null in the result object, you mean in the `POST` for the `Create` method?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the items of your drop-down list.

```
 <div class="editor-field">
        @{
            List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
                //You may want to loop to generate your items.                 
                items.Add(new SelectListItem
                {
                    //Or you code that generates your SelectListItems
                    Text = "Your_Text_1", 
                    Value = "Your Value_1",
                });
            items.Add(new SelectListItem
                {
                    //Or you code that generates your SelectListItems
                    Text = "Your_Text_2", 
                    Value = "Your_Value_2",
                });
        }
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PlayerA, items)           
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PlayerA)
```